# Partial Dependence Plot and categorical variables

Tags: statistics, categorical-data, explainable-ai, partial-dependence-plot

While reading about machine learning explainability and Partial Dependence Plot (PDP) in [this book](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/pdp.html), the following appeared when dealing with categorical variables:

> For each of the categories, we get a PDP estimate by forcing all data instances to have the same category.

- Is there a better explanation of how to deal with categorical features in PDP?
- How to do correctly Partial Dependence Plots with categorical variables